# Overplot trends in matplotlib: every loop gives additional trend

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the code below I get three different plots, and I would like to know how to combine them so that I have three lines on one plot. I thought there is something simple as overplot instead of plot, but somehow I could't find it.

Somehow I also need to adjust the x to the "longest" dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                    

big_array = [[4,5,4,5],[6,4,1],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in big_array:
    x = range(len(i))
    y = i
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "longest" dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`plt.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) this displays all the current figures that have been drawn and blocks the rest of the code until the figure window has been closed.

As you are in a loop of 3 iterations you code will display and block the figure at each call to show. Then when you close the window your loop will continue, creating another figure when you call `plt.plot()` and then displays it again when you call show.

To fix you should only call `plt.show()` at the end of your script:

```
big_array = [[4,5,4,5],[6,4,1],[1,2,3,4]]

for i in big_array:
    x = range(len(i))
    y = i
    plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Which will produce the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very simple solution but not intuitive at all. I guess it will be helpful for others.